# Cannot select tableview in storyboard and resize

Tags: swift

I can not select the tableview and resize it on the storyboard. It cant be selected but the prototype cell can be selected and resized. The problem is that i accidentally dragged and dropped the tableview in the viewcontroller by completely covering the screen which looks pretty bad when executed.

What might be the problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you have a proper list of all the views and controllers on the left hand side when you select the storyboard. There you can find your tableview select it and play with it.

Comment: i can select the tableview but can not resize it.